# How do I ask for the top 10 results in a JPA query?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using JPA in a Java project. Most of my functions are declared in JpaRepository interfaces using @Query annotations. For example, I have one defined this way:

```
List<Notification> findDelivered(@Param("patientId") long patientId);
```

I want to put a limit on this so as to get only the top 10 results. I tried adding "LIMIT 10" to the end of the query but that doesn't work.

I can find numerous examples where an instance of PageRequest is passed as the 2nd parameter to findDelivered. I tried that but it's a syntax error: the function is expecting an integer as the 2nd parameter (I don't know why).

Answer (score 0):

Try this for JPA get the first 10 results:
use the ***@Param("patientId")*** as ***NamedParameters***

```
List <notification> = notif.createQuery("select * from notification where patientId = :patientId order by patient_id")
    .setFirstResult(0) 
    .setMaxResults(10) 
    .getResultList();
```

or you can use ***Pageable*** :

```
Page<notification> findAll(Pageable pageable);
...
Page<notification> notification = NotificationRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(0, 10));
```

don't forget the ***Order***

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result

```java
Page<Notification> queryFirst10ByPatientId(long patientId, Pageable pageable);

Slice<Notification> findTop10ByPatientId(long patientId, Pageable pageable);

List<Notification> findFirst10ByPatientId(long patientId, Sort sort);

List<Notification> findTop10ByPatientId(long patientId, Pageable pageable);
```